# Why does msbuild give me a "language "C#" not supported" error when I try to open a project with OpenProjectAsync

Tags: c#, msbuild, roslyn

So I have this code :

```
 string path = Path.GetFullPath(@"C:\Users\Umut\source\repos\frmMain\frmMain.sln");
 string path2 = Path.GetFullPath(@"C:\Users\Umut\source\repos\frmMain\geometryLib\geometryLib.csproj");

 var workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();
 Solution solution =  workspace.OpenSolutionAsync(path).Result;
 Project project = workspace.OpenProjectAsync(path2).Result;
```

What I want to do is: Load the solution and every project inside of it. Loading the solution works, no errors. But when I try to load/open a project I get this error: Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Projekt "C:\Users\Umut\source\repos\frmMain\geometryLib\geometryLib.csproj" kann nicht geöffnet werden, da die Sprache "C#" nicht unterstützt wird.) ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Projekt "C:\Users\Umut\source\repos\frmMain\geometryLib\geometryLib.csproj" kann nicht geöffnet werden, da die Sprache "C#" nicht unterstützt wird.

The german part says: "Project cannot be opened, because the language "C#" is not supported.

How do I get rid of this error?

Edit: I use .NET Core 2.1 with these Nugets installed:

Microsoft.Build; Microsoft.Build.Framework; Microsoft.Build.Locator; Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core; all on v16.7.0

Microsoft.CodeAnalysy.CSharp; Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.MSBuild on v3.4.0

Comment: Which nuget packages do you use?

Comment: I edited my post. Sorry should have mentioned that in the post.

Comment: @Kalten damn you opened my eyes. I needed to install .csharp.workspaces for this work. Thanks man. Mind if I ask you something else about MSBuild?

Comment: If you have a new question, start a new question on Stack Overflow; that's not what comments are for. Also, referencing CSharp.Workspaces was correct, so add that as an answer -- you can do that too for your own questions!

Comment: Oh, thanks for reminding. Didn't knew that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer for this is installing the .CSharp.Workspaces NuGet Package.